# positioning of icon and button at header in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to align multiple icons at the header.Please suggest me where i'm going worng. Thanks in advance. Below is my code.
I want bars icon , header, search icon and then back button

```
 <div data-role="header">
 <a href="#mypanel" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" class=" buttonbg" style=" background-color:#D3D3D3;" >Bars</a>
   <h1>My Training </h1>
   <a href="#"  data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" >Bars</a>
   <a href="home.html" class=" ui-btn-right buttonbg buttontext" data-icon="back" data-mini="true" rel="external" style="border-radius:20px;">Back</a></div>
```

Comment: @ omar , thanks for the link you provided but that link does not work for me , what i want is one icon and button at the header

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/owx7u9w4/ like this?

Comment: @omar not exactly this, on right end side, i need a icon and button . I'm not sure is it possible or not. In link on right side both are buttons .(I need a icon and button with some text). 
Thank you for your reply